# How long to wait to see an app in Play Store results?

Tags: google-play

My app has been published in Google Play Store on 6/3/2023 (d/m/y) but it's still not findable searching in Play Store with keywords. There is a lot of competition in the category. The app can be found only searching with its own name.
Is it normal?
I have to wait? How much?
Has anyone direct experience?

I tried to search my app with the keywords used in Play Store app title & description.
I checked the whole result list and my app is not there.

Answer (score 0):

Possible problems found:

- PEGI 18: the app was rated as PEGI 18. I found out it's a bad bad thing! Google doesn't show the app to many people, not just based on declared date of birth! Requested PEGI 12!
- "new" in app title. Not "a brand new app!", not permitted. Used in a permitted way, but I'm afraid Google doesn't check and doesn't show correctly the app in results. Removed "new".

21/3/2023 PEGI 12 rejected. Accepted PEGI 18.
App still unfindable with title. I won't work on my app or upgrade a single line of code as long as the app is not findable on play store. Play store very bad experience.